# android 4.4 transparent png background issue

Tags: android, transparency, android-4.4-kitkat, nexus-5, png-transparency

I'm developing on Galaxy S3, Android 4.1.2.
Like any application, I'm using png images with transparent background, and also, there are a few images i go over and change every non-transparent pixel to a defferent color.
everything works just fine, but today I installed it on Nexus 5, android 4.4, and all the transparet background turned to black.
how can i make it transparent again?
Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: How are we supposed to help you, without any further information?

Comment: Hey, I'll be happy to supply every information you need. just tell me how can I helo you so you can help me (: